# Trying to extract from JSON when it's null

Tags: java, arrays, json, parsing

Will try to explain my question here.
I have a program that is suppose to parse through an incoming JSON-file that I receive from a web-crawler.

```
    public static void Scan(Article article) throws Exception
{
    //When running program, creates a error text-file inside java Project folder
    File file = new File("errorlogg.txt");
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file, true);

    // if file doesn't exists, then create it
    if (!file.exists()) 
    {
        file.createNewFile();
    }

    //Setting up an URL HttpURLConnection given DOI
    URL urlDoi = new URL (article.GetElectronicEdition());

    //Used for debugging 
    System.out.println("Initial DOI: " + urlDoi);

    //Transform from URL to String
    String doiCheck = urlDoi.toString();

    //Redirect from IEEE Xplore toe IEEE Computer Society
    if(doiCheck.startsWith("http://dx."))
    {
        doiCheck = doiCheck.replace("http://dx.doi.org/", "http://doi.ieeecomputersociety.org/");
        urlDoi = new URL(doiCheck);
    }

    HttpURLConnection connDoi = (HttpURLConnection) urlDoi.openConnection();

    // Make the logic below easier to detect redirections
    connDoi.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);  

    String doi = "{\"url\":\"" + connDoi.getHeaderField("Location") + "\",\"sessionid\":\"abc123\"}";

    //Setting up an URL to translation-server
    URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:1969/web");
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

    writer.write(doi);
    writer.flush();

    String line;
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));



    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null ) 
    {
        //Used to see of we get something from stream
        System.out.println(line);

        //Incoming is JSONArray, so create new array and parse fill it with incoming information
        JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(line);
        JSONObject obj = jsonArr.getJSONObject(0);

        //Check if names from DBLP is the same as translators get
        //AuthorName, from field creators
        JSONArray authorNames = obj.getJSONArray("creators");
        ArrayList<Author> TranslationAuthors = new ArrayList<Author>();
```

Here is the bit of the code that I'm talking about. As you can see I wanna run this code when I get some information from the bufferreader. 
My problem is that my program doesn't seem to skip when I don't get a valid JSON. Instead it runs to this line of code:

```
        JSONArray authorNames = obj.getJSONArray("creators")
```

And then is forced to exit since it can't get the field "creators" since there is none.
How can I do to make sure that my program don't encounter this problem? How can I easy put it in the error-logg file that I create that I could't collect any information.

Comment: You could try the `obj.has("creators")` which returns a boolean of whether or not the key is in the object. If it is not, then log it. If you want the program to fail, use a try-catch block to attempt to execute the code. If it fails, then log it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are working with a `org.json.JSONObject`? If that's so, there is a `has` method, which can be used to avoid the `JSONException` in case the key does not exist.

```
 JSONArray authorNames = null;
 if (obj.has("creators")) {
   authorNames = obj.getJSONArray("creators");
 }
```